# Why is the idiom 'make one's skin crawl', not 'make one's skin crawled over'?

Tags: idioms

I became curious about the etymology of the idiom '*make one's skin crawl*'. So, I searched for it and found this [source](https://www.idioms.online/make-ones-skin-crawl/). According to the source, the idiom refers to a feeling similar to having something, such as an insect, crawl over one's skin. But then, shouldn't it be the insect that is crawling, not the skin? It doesn't seem to make much sense that the skin can crawl, hence the question.

Why isn't it '*make one's skin crawled **over***'?

Comment: Language is not logical. It's not about what makes more sense.

Comment: @CJDennis I understand any language is full of exceptions and logical inconsistencies. But if you simply says sth is sth because it is the way it is, what's the meaning of asking a question in this website?

Comment: @CJDennis I think language is not solely about what makes more sense, but still it is quite a lot about what makes more sense.

Comment: I think in this case you're unlikely to get a satisfying answer. The answer is probably "just because". Idioms make even less sense than other phrases.

Comment: @CJDennis Thanks, even your saying so helped me quite a bit.

Comment: It makes your skin crawl -- sensations of the skin forming ripples.

Comment: (Have you never had "goose bumps"???)

Comment: @CJDennis Oh, I don't think it's so hard to satisfy this one.

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks a lot. That makes good sense to me. However, it seems that your explanation disagrees with tchrist's answer which is not related with skin forming ripples. Do you think people actually have different understandings about what the word describes?

Answer (score 3):

This is a perfectly normal use of the verb *crawl*.  From the OED, with selected senses and a small subset of citations:

> 5. *transferred*. To be all ‘alive’ with crawling things; also *figurative*.
>
>    - 1576   A. Fleming tr. Pherecydes in *Panoplie Epist*. 204  
>       All my skin cralled with lyce.
>    - 1902   R. Kipling *Traffics & Discov*. (1904) 185 
>        There's a whole switchboard full o' nickel-plated muckin's which I haven't begun to play with yet. The starboard side's crawlin' with 'em.
>    - 1924   P. G. Wodehouse *Bill the Conqueror* vii. 143 
>        ‘He must be quite rich.’ ‘Crawling with money.’
>    - 1945   E. Waugh *Brideshead Revisited* 88  
>       The country is crawling with Communists.
> 6. To have a sensation as of things crawling over the skin; to feel ‘creepy’, to ‘creep’.
>
>    - 1880   R. Grant *Confessions Frivolous Girl* 161 
>        Kissing a ragged infant or two, whose dirtiness positively made me crawl.
>    - 1889   M. E. Wilkins *Far-away Melody* (1891) 15 
>        You make me crawl all over, talkin' so much about dyin'.

So it made your skin have a sensation of things crawling over it. It felt a;ll creepy and crawly. :)

For sense 6, they provide a citation from Middle English and in a note suggest a possible French origin:

> > The first quot. here may really be from French *crouler* ‘to shake, tremble, quiver, quake’ (Cotgrave): see **ᴄʀᴏᴡʟ** *v*.
> >
> > - *a*1400  (▸*a*1325)    *Cursor Mundi* (Gött.) l. 3567  
> >    Quen þat he [sc. a man] bicomis alde..It crepis crouland [*Trin. Cambr*. hit crepeþ crulyng, *Fairf*. wiþ crepinge croulis] in his bac.

So: “When that a man becomes old, it creeps crawling (or *crowling*) on his back.”

Comment: Thanks a lot! It clearly answers my question. By the way, do you think it's possible that sense 6 is actually a back-formation of the idiom?